# what does it mean for a to BJT operating at the edge between the active and saturation modes?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bjt

ive recently been fascinated with diodes and was wondering how i'd design a circuit that works at the edge of the breakpoint between the active and saturation mode. How would the circuit be analysed?

Comment: When something is on the boundary between two models and the transistion bewteen the models is smooth, then by definition you can analyse it with either model and the result will be the same.

Comment: What definition of 'saturation' are you using?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen basically i'd be designing a circuit that gives the same output when analysed in the saturation and also when analysed in the active model?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany the Emiter-Base region is forward bias and the base-collector is is also in forward bias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming moderate collector current, the region where about 0.2V < Vce can be analyzed as anywhere else in the active region, with suitably adjusted hfe. So you could use small signal analysis about the point where Vce = 0.7V without much risk, for suitably small signal amplitude (such that the deviation from linearity is 'small').

Consider the curves below for a real transistor (2N4401)

[image]

The upper graph shows that the characteristics at Vce = 1.0V are not markedly different from those at 10V. The lower graph shows the gain variation in the saturation region. A vertical line indicates constant gain with decreasing Vce. As you can see the curves flatten more and more as Vce drops, so the gain will be less, but the transistor still behaves similarly to how it behaves with higher Vce until the voltage is very low.

If it's a high frequency small signal analysis- the collector-base capacitance increases with the reduced bias so that will have an effect.

Answer (score 1):

Once a junction gets saturated, it takes awhile for it to react and come ***out*** of saturation. I believe this is where the "Charge Control" model, or Gummel-Poon model, comes into play.

The time delay for a saturated junction to react is modelled by waiting for a capacitor to discharge. From Wikipedia, the basic model is:

[image]

Courtney of Berkely, you can look through associated math [here](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~hu/Chenming-Hu_ch8.pdf).

Comment: so given a specific circuit with 2 unknown component cariable (resistors or caps) and i am to design the circuit to work just in between the saturation and active mode how would i go about implementing that?

Comment: @leftbrain without seeing the circuit, I'll assume a common emitter design. Two resistors set base voltage, emitter = base -0.6V. Resistor on emitter limits current, and same current goes thrugh a collector resistor. IF collector voltage is *very close* to base voltage, you are *very close* to saturation. Adding an AC signal to base should be enough to saturate the transistor.